# Extract files from tar file using wildcard

Tags: linux, tar

Can any one tell me how to extract a tar file using wildcards, for example

```
$ tar -xvf file1_*.tar dir1/
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you trying to extract multiple tar files using one command, or are you trying to extract files from a single tar file using a wildcard?  Sorry, just want to be absolutely clear about your question.

Comment: I want to extract a single tar file using wildcard

Comment: So you want to extract all files of the format `file1_*.tar` from a single tar file?  That is a completely different question.

Answer (score 2):

You can execute the following in the same dir as the tars.

```
for filename in ./file1_*.tar; do tar -xvf $filename -C ./dir1/; done
```

Comment: Iam getting error as follows:tar: file1_*.tar: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now

Comment: Are you executing this command in the same directory as the tar files? can you paste the output of `ls` in the directory containing the tar files?

Comment: I am executing command in the same folder. The output of ls is : file2_14-Aug-2014-19-45-22.tar
file2_14-Aug-2014-19-45-22.tar
file1_14-Aug-2014-19-45-22.tar

Comment: Ok try using: `for filename in ./*.tar; do tar -xvf $filename -C ./dir1/; done`

Comment: Error tar: ./*.tar: Cannot open: No such file or directory

Comment: Please copy the commands you're using directly from your commandline and paste them here for us.

Answer (score 0):

To extract multiple tar files in a single directory, try the following (from the directory containing the files):

```
ls file1_*.tar | xargs -I{} tar -xvf {} dir1/
```

The command lists the tar files using your pattern in the current directory, piping them to `xargs`, which will execute the `tar` command on each file using the pattern `tar -xvf {filename} dir1/`.

To see exactly what will be performed, modify the above command to

```
ls file1_*.tar | xargs -I{} echo tar -xvf {} dir1/
```

`xargs` is an incredibly powerful tool to learn how to use from the commandline where a single command needs to be performed on multiple inputs, and will often save you a lot of time.

[This](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/19840/extract-multiple-tar-gz-files-with-a-single-tar-call) post also has another alternative.

Comment: Getting error ls: cannot access file1_*.tar: No such file or directory

Comment: Did you use the `ls` command correctly?  It seems like you're passing just the wildcard to tar.  I've edited with a debug sample.

Comment: I used exactly what you have given, but getting error

Comment: You seem to be asking a completely different question to the answers given - can you clarify your original question?

Comment: Please copy the commands you're using directly from your commandline and paste them here for us.

Comment: Did you understand my question?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59368/discussion-between-roelofs-and-user27).

Comment: I've moved the discussion to chat - please join me there